# Selecting special characters only from table with Japanese name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server on a table of Japanese names. I'm trying to return any field that contains a special character(eg, - / $ .) but it's also returning any Japanese character.

```
select names from nameTable
where 
(names <> '' and names not like N'%[a-z0-9]%')
```

I'm using various versions of the above to get my results and it does technical work.

Just wondering if anyone has any advice on how to exclude the Japanese characters from my results.

If more information is needed please ask.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Define your requirements more precisely and you can accomplish your goal. Your stated goal is to look for "special" characters but your logic doesn't do that. Rather your logic looks for any character that is not within the typical roman character alphabet (including numerals). So guess what - any non-roman character is "special" according to your logic. So that won't work with kanji/katakana letters (or any other non-roman characters) **at all**. Zack has provided a start - and you really, REALLY, need to understand the japanese alphabets to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't working because you're specifying ASCII characters in your `LIKE` clause. So any non-ASCII characters (including Japanese characters) will show up in your result.

There may well be a better answer (including @denial's suggestion to create a CLR function). But another possible solution is to hard-code the special characters you need. Something like this:

```
select * from JapaneseText
where 
    chars like N'%[[!"#$%&''()*+`-./:;<=>?@\^_]%'
    -- separate check for ']', to avoid it 
    -- being interpreted as the end of the character class
    or chars like N'%]%'
```

Of course, these are just the special characters from the ASCII table. You'd have to tweak the solution to handle more characters (smart quotes, dashes, etc.) But then it would really start to get unwieldy, so you might very well be better off approaching it from another angle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I understand that I was asking to something a bit tough. I went down a rabbit hole trying to use unicode ranges after the 'like' to achieve what I wanted but it doesn't seem to be working. eg, like N'%[^\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uffef\u4e00]%'  Will have a look at the CLR stuff, otherwise hard-coding it is.

Answer (score 0):

It comes in mind that you should use CLR UDF's for that purpose. Seems to me that you couldn't achieve this with `LIKE`.
That is you could make an assembly, eg. written in C# which could return regex matches from a given column. More on CLR UDF's here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/